# Is there any different way to write if...if else... statement sentence in this case?

Tags: java, if-statement

```
public class Sales {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ursales = 6000;
        int target = 3000;

        if (ursales >= 2 * target) {
            System.out.println("performance Excellent");
            System.out.println("bouns 1000");
        } else if (ursales >= 1.5 * target) {
            System.out.println("performance Fine");
            System.out.println("bouns 500");
        } else if (ursales >= target) {
            System.out.println("performance Satisfactory");
            System.out.println("bouns 100");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You Are Fired!");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to write each statement like:

```
performance = "...";
bonus = "...";
```

but it didn't work.

Can someone tell me if there is other possible way to write this statements without `System.out.println`?

Comment: Can you show your attempt?

Comment: public class Sales {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ursales = 6000;
        int target = 3000;

Comment: You can [edit] your question.

Comment: What do you mean 'without `System.out.println`'?  Currently all the code (sample) does is print to the console.  Doing something else would be changing behaviour...  I mean, you could use `System.out.print` `printf`, etc. if you just don't like that specific method?

Comment: All clear now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SOmething like this?

```
String performance;
int bonus;

if (ursales >= 2 * target) {
    performance = "performance Excellent";
    bonus = 1000;
} else if (ursales >= 1.5 * target) {
    performance = "fine";
    bonus = 500;
} else ... etc..

System.out.println("performance " + performance );
System.out.printkn("bouns " +  bonus );
```

Comment: This would have been decent if you threw some type of exception on else, and this doesn't compile. I get where you were going with this but it looks just as bad as OP.

Answer (score 1):

Are you ready for verbosity? We define a **Bonus** interface that determines if a sales hits the target which is defined by implementation. We then create a Stream, which is ordered, and then return the **first** result in the stream that **filter** meets. The upside to this approach is that if you want to add more bonuses in the future it's extremely easy to do so.

```java
    interface Bonus {

        boolean hit(int sales, int target);

    }

    static class ExcellentBonus implements Bonus {

        @Override
        public boolean hit(int sales, int target) {
            return sales >= target * 2;
        }

    }

    static class FineBonus implements Bonus {

        @Override
        public boolean hit(int sales, int target) {
            return sales >= target * 1.5;
        }
    }

    static class SatisfactoryBonus implements Bonus {


        @Override
        public boolean hit(int sales, int target) {
            return sales >= target;
        }
    }

    static class FiredBonus implements Bonus {

        @Override
        public boolean hit(int sales, int target) {
            return sales < target;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sales = 100;

        int target = 50;

        Bonus bonus = Stream.of(new ExcellentBonus(), new FineBonus(), new SatisfactoryBonus())
                .filter(b -> b.hit(sales, target)).findFirst().orElse(new FiredBonus());

    }
```

Comment: Hahahaha, +1 for you.

Comment: Seems like it wants to be an `enum` (or at least, have some `enum StandardBonuses implements Bonus`) rather than a bunch of separate classes.

Comment: Yeah you could go with that approach but **typically** enums are used in cases where the elements are finite, such as days, months, units of time. In this case, it's easily possible that there could be more, or less, bonuses. 

Also, it's worth noting that you would create a package and have 4 classes. That's an extremely small amount of classes and easily navigable. That being said, I get the idea that an enum **could** be useful.

Comment: Nice answer. One remark though: the order in which the stream is created initially does matter. The Bonusses must be added in descending order. An explicit ordering would fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `System.out.println()` you can use `System.out.print()`. This will not create any new lines when printing to the console.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a StringBuilder to concat all the strings you need and print them all at once in the end.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is similar to [@Jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60130994/4216641), but uses a slightly different contract. It is similar in the way that it defines a class to represent the result of the performance evaluation. It differs in the form that it allows defining a map of factors to performance evaluations.

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/3C0Znk)

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final String FORMAT = "Performance %s\nbonus %d";
        final Map<Double, PerformanceResult> performanceResultMap = new HashMap<>();
        performanceResultMap.put(2.0, new PerformanceResult("Excellent", 1000));
        performanceResultMap.put(1.5, new PerformanceResult("Fine", 500));
        performanceResultMap.put(1.0, new PerformanceResult("Satisfactory", 100));

        final PerformanceResult excellent =
                calculatePerformance(200.0, 100.0, performanceResultMap);
        System.out.println(String.format(FORMAT, excellent.getMessage(), excellent.getBonus()));

        final PerformanceResult fine = calculatePerformance(150.0, 100.0, performanceResultMap);
        System.out.println(String.format(FORMAT, fine.getMessage(), fine.getBonus()));

        final PerformanceResult satisfactory =
                calculatePerformance(100.0, 100.0, performanceResultMap);
        System.out.println(String.format(FORMAT, satisfactory.getMessage(), satisfactory.getBonus()));

        try {
            calculatePerformance(0, 100, performanceResultMap);
            throw new IllegalStateException("Exception should have been thrown");
        } catch (final NoFittingPerformanceResultFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Expected exception thrown");
        }
    }

    public static PerformanceResult calculatePerformance(
            final double actual,
            final double target,
            final Map<Double, PerformanceResult> performanceResultMap) {
        return performanceResultMap.keySet().stream()
                .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())
                .filter(factor -> actual >= target * factor)
                .findFirst()
                .map(performanceResultMap::get)
                .orElseThrow(NoFittingPerformanceResultFoundException::new);
    }
}

class PerformanceResult {
    private final String message;
    private final int bonus;

    PerformanceResult(final String message, final int bonus) {
        this.message = Objects.requireNonNull(message);
        this.bonus = bonus;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public int getBonus() {
        return bonus;
    }
}

class NoFittingPerformanceResultFoundException extends IllegalStateException {}
```

Comment: I like the immutability of PerformanceResult and the usage of Objects#requireNonNull, but checking if the int parameter bonus is null would never throw a NullPointException (I could be wrong). I like the idea of creating a Map to maintain the threshold and the result, great idea. The only thing I would change is instead of returning null silently in calculatePerformance I would throw an IllegalStateException indicating that no performance could be calculated.

Comment: I know that the `orElse(null)` is dodgy, but for a POC, it should be enough ;) the `requireNonNull(...)` on the primitive was an oversight, superfluous and has been removed. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Jason okay you got me, I have added a custom exception that is thrown if no fitting result has been found =)